# What exactly is the derivative of a function?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, graphing-functions, intuition

I am very new to calculus. I have only just started it in school and when I have looked at other people explaining this question they use a lot of terminology I am unfamiliar with and it gets very overwhelming. I just want to know, is the derivative of a function of a graph a way of finding the graph’s gradient at (x, y)? Also, what exactly is the difference between $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}$ and f(x) = … and when should I use the different functions. Thank you for any help I appreciate it so much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Differential calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_calculus#Derivative) is a good introduction.

Comment: @codey7rack: Have you tried asking your instructor? I suspect that this person would know better than most the terminology with which you are familiar, whereas people here can only guess. Alternatively, perhaps you could quote the explanations you've seen, and try to convey what seems to be overwhelming you, so that people here don't unhelpfully duplicate such remarks.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment: The derivative is *many* things. It starts with

> The derivative is the slope of a line tangent to the graph of the function, if the graph has a tangent.

(which I guess looks familiar to you) and continues all the way through

> The derivative of a real-valued function $f$ in a domain $D$ is the Lagrangian section of the cotangent bundle $T^*(D)$ that gives the connection form for the unique flat connection on the trivial $\Bbb R$-bundle $D ×\Bbb R$ for which the graph of $f$ is parallel.

(which is probably not familiar to you at all, and honestly, a bit overwhelming to me). There are dozens upon dozens of different actively used notions of derivative, all trying to capture the same concept from different angles. What *you* think the derivative is depends entirely on your current level, what math you are currently doing, and your current mood.

In my opinion, it is for this reason nearly impossible to truly answer the question "What exactly is the derivative of a function?" The best you will get is a list of different definitions like the two above. None of them wrong, but not all of them suitable to you, and *none* of them the "true" notion of derivative.

Comment: okay thank you. yea the slope of a line tangent to the graph sounds familiar to me, the rest look like voodoo curses. thank you though, may i please ask, what does tangent mean in this context? i always thought tangent was a ratio of two values, although thats really only a guess from what ive listened to from eavesdropping in class etc. i only remember using it in the sohcahtoa equations so for it to be used in relation to a gradient does confuse me.

Comment: @codey7rack Yes, the second quote is meant to look like voodoo curses to the majority of the people who reads this answer. In the context of the first definition I quoted, tangent means a straight line that is as close as possible to the graph at that point. There are, again, several ways to formally define what "as close as possible" means. But at this level, pure visual intuition is probably good enough to start with.

Comment: @codey7rack: Are you familiar with the concept of the *limit* of a function?

Comment: @Arthur so does this mean the tangent at the point (x, y)? does that make sense? like is the tangent meant to only touch one point of the graph at that point (x, y)? and is that tangent value describe as the "tangent at point (x, y)?" or am i just confusing you?

Comment: @Joe no i am not :/

Comment: @codey7rack The tangent isn't meant to only touch one point of the graph (although that does happen some times). It is meant to touch the graph at $(x,y)$, and then we don't really care much whether it touches or intersects anywhere else (unless that's _exactly_ what we care about: "Where else does the tangent touch the function?" is a semi-common exercise).

Comment: @codey7rack: Please look at this [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-limits-new/ab-1-2/v/introduction-to-limits-hd) introduction to limits. The derivative $f'(x)$ is defined as $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \, .$$Actually, once you have finished learning about limits, you could probably look at the Khan academy website's article about derivatives as well.

Comment: @Arthur ohhh okay so can the tangent just be visualized as a line passing through (x, y) ?  and in a question where i am asked to find the tangent of the gradient at (x, y) what would that look like ? like would you be able to give me an example just so i can kinda wrap my head around it please?

Answer (score 1):

$f'$ is known as the *derivative* or *gradient function*, and $f'(x)$ tells us the gradient of $f$ at the point $x$. For instance, if $f(x)=x^2$, then $f'(x)=2x$, meaning at any point $(x,f(x))$ that lies on the graph of $f$, the gradient is $2x$.

The graph of $f$ can also be described as the set of points in the $x$-$y$ plane that satisfy $y=x^2$. Then, we can write $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$  (not $\frac{dx}{dy}=2x$), which has the same meaning as $f'(x)=2x$, but tries to capture a slightly different idea. While the notation $f'(x)=2x$ emphasises that $f'$ is the gradient function, the notation $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$ tries to capture the geometric content of the derivative. Roughly speaking, $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$ means that if we start at the point $(x,y)$, and move a small distance $\Delta x$ along the graph, then the change in $y$-coordinate $\Delta y$ will be about $2x$ times the change in $x$-coordinate $\Delta x$. More precisely, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the *limit* of $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ as $\Delta x$ approaches $0$:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{(x+\Delta x)^2-x^2}{\Delta x} \, .
$$

---

$f$ is a function—not a graph. A function can be thought of as a machine that takes each input to a particular output. We commonly denote an arbitrary input to the function using the letter $x$ (but there's no particular reason to—it's just convention). So $f(x)=x^2$ means that the function $f$ takes each number to the square of that number. For instance, $f(1)=1$, $f(47)=47^2$, and $f(\pi)=\pi^2$. Technically, $f$ is the function, whereas $f(x)$ is the *value* of the function $f$ at $x$. In practice, it is common to say that $f(x)$ is the function.

The letter $x$ is just being used to refer to any particular point on the $x$-axis.

I don't think I completely understand your next question, but $\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$ and $f'(x)=2x$ are both very common notations, and you can use whichever you like (the first is called Leibnizian notation, and the second is Lagrange notation or prime notation). Generally, if a function is defined by an equation $y=\ldots$ then it is customary to write $\frac{dy}{dx}=\ldots$ If a function is defined by $f(x)=\ldots$, then the derivative is denoted by $f'(x)=\ldots$ Some people express a strong preference for one of these notations over the other. Personally, I think both of them are useful in their own way.

$f'$ is the gradient function, and $f'(x)$ is the gradient of $f$ at $x$. For instance, if $f(x)=x^2$, then $f'(x)=2x$. So $f'(5)=10$ means "if you draw a tangent to the graph of $f$ at the point $(5,25)$, then the gradient of that tangent will be $10$". If you plot the graph of $f'$ in the $x$-$y$ plane, then at each point $(x,y)$ of $f$, the value $y$ tells us the gradient of $f$ at $x$.

You can find the tangent to the graph of $f$ at the point $(x_1,y_1)$ by working out $f'(x_1)$. For example, if $f(x)=3x^2$, then $f'(x)=6x$. So the tangent to $f$ at the point $(10,300)$ must have gradient $f'(10)=60$. If the line $\ell$, given by $y=mx+c$, is tangent to $f$ at $(10,300)$, then it must be the case that $m=60$. Also, $\ell$ passes through $(10,300)$, and so $300=60(10)+c$, meaning that $c=-300$. Therefore, $\ell$ has equation $y=60x-300$. In general, the tangent to the graph of $f$ at the point $(x_1,y_1)$ has the equation
$$
y = f'(x_1)(x-x_1)+y_1 \, .
$$

Comment: so f  can represent the graph itself? and x is just a point on the x axis on the graph itself? this " Roughly speaking, dy/dx=2x means that if we start at the point (x,y), and move a small distance Δx along the graph, then the change in y-coordinate Δy will be about 2x times the change in x-coordinate Δx" made a lot of sense to me and i appreciate you breaking it down like this. however when would i use this equation instead of just differentiating and using f'(x)? is it when i already have both x and y values? this was very helpful though thank you Joe

Comment: when you say gradient function... does that mean it is a function that will give me a value of the gradient at a certain point? i think i remember a question we had in class that had us put an x value into the derived function (f'(x)) and then will that value into the equation y=mx + c and then find the constant to give us our y value, then that would give us the tangent at that coordinate. does this make sense or have i just completely worded this incorrectly?

Comment: @codey7rack: Good questions. See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you so much, seriously. the terminology is still a bit wacky for me but i am new to this and you still helped me a long way to understanding the concept of things. i really appreciate it and i hope you have a great day/night. much thanks

Comment: @codey7rack: I'm very glad I could help, and I am pleased that you are inquisitive enough to ask all these questions. This will be help you massively in your future studies. Good luck!